How to specify multiple labels in Bazel rule srcs?
This works:
"srcs": attr.label_list( allow_files=[".proto"] ),

But I want also to pass in ProtoInfo targets.
"srcs": attr.label_list( allow_files=[".proto"] )
        + 
        attr.label_list( providers = [[ProtoInfo],] )

And this failed with "unsupported binary operation: Attribute + Attribute".

You could do "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files=[".proto"], providers=[ProtoInfo]) however then targets in srcs would have to both produce .proto files and provide a ProtoInfo provider, which is unlikely to work.
It would probably be better to split these into two attributes, something like:
"srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files=[".proto"]),
"deps": attr.label_list(providers=[ProtoInfo]),


I use deps for "import", when one proto references another proto.

Anyway, I ended up with "srcs": attr.label_list(allow_files=True, providers=[ProtoInfo]). This allows to pass in both files and ProtoInfo targets. Then inside rule impl I call fail() in case file path does not end with '.proto'.

Oh. This broke filegroup(name="x", srcs=["x.proto"])   my_rule(srcs=[":x"])
